# How to Print Max Value of Character?

Tags: java, character

Although it is a very Initial level question but I find it complex one. Actually I want to know **what is happening behind the scene**? Why Character.MAX_VALUE does not print the Max Value of char(Which is 65535) and MAX_VALUE-1 does.

```
    System.out.println("Byte Max Value: "+Byte.MAX_VALUE);//print 127 Ok!
    System.out.println("Character Max Value: "+Character.MAX_VALUE);//print ?(Question Mark)
    System.out.println(Character.MAX_VALUE-1);//print 65534
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because in the second line, `Character.MAX_VALUE` is concatenated with the String.

As the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) states:

> The string concatenation operator + (§15.18.1), which, when given a
>   String operand and an integral operand, will convert the integral
>   operand to a String representing its value in decimal form, and then
>   produce a newly created String that is the concatenation of the two
>   strings

As `Character.MAX_VALUE` is not printable, you don't see it.

In the third case, your doing a substraction with an `int`, thus the whole expression is casted to `int` and it prints an `int` value.

Also as the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18) states:

> The binary + operator performs addition when applied to two operands
>   of numeric type, producing the sum of the operands.
>
> [...]
>
> Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands (§5.6.2).
>
> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands, each of which  must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
>
> 1. [...]
> 2. Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or
>      both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
>    If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
>
>    Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted
>      to float.
>
>    Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted
>      to long.
>
>    **Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int**.

If you've done

```
System.out.println("Character Max Value: "+(Character.MAX_VALUE+0));
```

It would print `Character Max Value: 65535`

Answer (score 5):

Character.MAX_VALUE is \uFFFF.  This is not a printable character by definition. When you perform an operation like -1 or +1 you are changing the type to an `int`

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ffff/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

> Implicit casting by adding `0` to `Character.MIN_VALUE` or `Character.MAX_VALUE` works well.
>   You can also explicitly cast to an int, to get the `MIN_VALUE` and `MAX_VALUE` With two `println()` methods....
>   `System.out.println("char min. value: " + (int)Character.MIN_VALUE);`
>   `System.out.println("char max. value: " + (int)Character.MAX_VALUE);`
>       In your third line you have...
>   `System.out.println(Character.MAX_VALUE-1);//print 65534`
>       You are essentially implicitly casting the Unicode maximum value to an int   and then subtracting 1 from that maximum value. In Unicode format the range is   from `U+0000` to `U+FFFF`, the `FFFF` (`65535`) is the numeric upper range of the char primitive data type and `0000` (`0`) is the numeric lower range of the char data type. In the two `println()` methods above, is the `Character` class which is the wrapper class for the `char` primitive data type, it simply takes the primitive `char` and wraps it up in the `Character` class. Allowing us to treat it as an object and giving us access to the fields and methods of the `Character` wrapper class.
>   Then using the `MIN_VALUE` and `MAX_VALUE` fields with the dot operator we can cast these Unicode values to int's   and the output is the range expressed as decimal numbers is `0` to `65535`
>   Of course it is understood that if something can be implicitly cast it can also   be explicitly cast.
>       We are also only considering here the Basic Multilingual Plane (Plane 0).   Normally a Unicode code point is referred to by writing `"U+"` followed by its   four digit hexadecimal number. So these code points in Plane 0 are expressed by a four   digit hexadecimal number, nothing to difficult. The Unicode code points are nothing more than four digit hexadecimal numbers. Plane `0` has a range of `65535` possible characters that it can represent. Wikipedia has a good article on Unicode.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode